# How to plot line (polygonal chain) with numpy/scipy/matplotlib with minimal smoothing

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scipy, spline

I am trying to plot a line in matplotlib.. I am searching for the right type of interpolation.. I want something like this

[image: taken from canvasxpress.org/line.html]

where every line is smoothed. I tried several combination of scipy and matplotlib, such as

```
x_new = np.arange(x, x_length, 1)
tck = interpolate.splrep(x, y, s=3)
y_new = interpolate.splev(x_new, tck, der=0)
ax.plot(x_new, y_new, color+lstyle)
```

but the best result I get is

[image: my result]

The line represents **an increasing variable**.. so it is a wrong representation. What can I search for?

Thanks

Edit: I am thinking about implementing a method from myself, but I don't know if it has been already done.. pseudo code is the following

```
take x and y
calculate spline for each three points 
x[0], x[1], x[2] ... x[1], x[2], x[3] ... and so on
for each y[n] sums every computation done for it and divide by number of 
computations (i.e. y[1] is computed for triplette x[0..2] and x[1..3] so the 
sum is divided by two (average for each point is taken as its value)
```

Comment: why are you interpolating?  Is this for aesthetics or are you claiming to know the values between your data points?

Comment: @tcaswell I am interpolating for both reasons, mainly for aesthetics

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For that type of graph, you want *monotonic* interpolation.  The [`PchipInterpolator`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html) class (which you can refer to by its shorter alias `pchip`) in scipy.interpolate can be used:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import pchip
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Data to be interpolated.
x = np.arange(10.0)
y = np.array([5.0, 10.0, 20.0, 15.0, 13.0, 22.0, 20.0, 15.0, 12.0, 16.0])

# Create the interpolator.
interp = pchip(x, y)

# Dense x for the smooth curve.
xx = np.linspace(0, 9.0, 101)

# Plot it all.
plt.plot(xx, interp(xx))
plt.plot(x, y, 'bo')
plt.ylim(0, 25)
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: It was what I was searching for :) Thanks

Comment: Is there an N-D version? :)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not a display problem. It is an interpolation problem. You are interpolating using spline functions. Picking the right interpolation method is very much depending on the kind of data you have. You cannont expect to have an interpolation function which will behave right in every circumstances (the interpolation have no way to know that your function is increasing).

Comment: try using another interpolating function, like `scipy.interpolate.interp1d()`, tuning the parameter `kind` until it satisfies you

Comment: thanks I will try it.  @Nicolas yes I was wrong.. I'll change the title and the content of this post accordingly

Comment: @flebool I tried all possible values for kind but none satisfied me.. :(

Answer (score 1):

You should either look at

scipy.interpolate.LSQUnivariateSpline and play with k parameter (degree of the spline)

or scipy.interpolate.UnivariateSpline and play with k and s parameter.

Comment: I tried but it was not what I was looking for. Anyway I upvoted your answer because it can be useful and for your time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

It is important to understand that the interpolation is not just a line for visualization. It is a mathematical model representing how you think the system behaves (the system which generates the data that you measured). Different types of interpolations represent different assumptions about the system.

So, if you know that your system is such that a variable can only increase, you should fit an appropriate model (i.e. use the appropriate interpolation). Looking at your data, it looks like a 2nd degree polynomial or an exponential function might fit well. A Loess (local regression) fit will also work. You can use either tailored functions like numpy.polyfit(), or generic curve fitting with scipy.optimize.curve_fit(). If you have further knowledge about the system, you should use it to select which model to fit.

Comment: I know.. I am a bit nescient in interpolation, sorry. I tried polynomial fittings but it was not what I was searching for. Anyway I upvoted you for your time. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I have looked around a bit. What you want is called

Monotone cubic interpolation,

see wikipedia [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation). You have a discussion on mathexchange about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45218/implementation-of-monotone-cubic-interpolation) and I have found an implementation in python [here](http://code.google.com/p/pywafo/source/browse/trunk/pywafo/src/wafo/pychip.py?r=152). Let me know if this works!

Comment: I've tried your solution and it works but there is a similar function in scipy.interpolate.. Anyway I upvoted your answer for your effort :) Thanks