# how to draw a nonlinear function using matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I would like to draw the curve a generic cubic function using matplotlib. I want to draw curves that are defined by functions such as: x^3 + y^3 + y^2 + 2xy^2 = 0. Is this possible to do?

Comment: Here is what helped me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935098/how-to-plot-line-polygonal-chain-with-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-with-minimal-smoo

Comment: ^Not quite what i'm looking for, but thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One obvious way to do this is to found the `(x,y)` pairs satisfy the relationship, by numerically solving the equation.

```
from scipy import optimize
f=lambda x, y: (x**3+y**3+y**2+2*x*y*y-0)**2
y_range=linspace(-1, 1, 100)
x_range=[optimize.fmin(f,0,args=(y,), disp=0) for y in y_range]
xr=linspace(-1,1)
yr=linspace(-1,1)
X, Y=meshgrid(xr, yr)
Z=f(X, Y)
plt.plot(x_range, y_range, 'k')
plt.contourf(xr, yr, Z, levels=linspace(0,0.001,51), alpha=0.5)
plt.colorbar()
```

[image]

The black line is what you want. The contour is just to show how the function behaves around 0. `optimize.fmin()` is not the most efficient solver here, just keep it simple.

When the absolute values of `x` or `y` are large, you are essentially plotting `x+0.4496y=0` and you don't need to do all these above.

Answer (score 0):

my 2 cents:
x^3+y^3+y^2+2xy^2=0
y^2=-x^3-y^3-2xy^2
y^2>0 => -x^3-y^3-2xy^2>0 => x^3+y^3+2xy^2<0 =>
x(x^2+2y^2)+y^3<0 => x(x^2+2y^2)<-y^3 => (x^2+2y^2)<-y^3/x
0<(x^2+2y^2) => 0<-y^3/x => 0>y^3/x =>
(x>0 && y<0) || (x<0 && y>0)
your graph will span across the 2nd and 4th quadrants