# SciPy Monotone Cubic Spline Interpolation

Tags: python, scipy, spline

I am drawing some graphs in PyQt and I need to use [monotone cubic spline interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation) to get nice smooth lines (that don't extend their boundries). SciPi has a `CubicSpline` object which I was able to get working, however it is not "monotonic". Is there an easy way to achieve this? Regretfully my knowledge of math is basic and I really don't know much calculus so reading the documentation has been... unfruitful.

For what it's worth here's my snippet to extrapolate a smoothed spline from a series of data points and plot them into a QRectF:

```
def range_map(value, from_min, from_max, to_min, to_max):
    left_span = from_max - from_min
    right_span = to_max  - to_min
    value_scaled = float(value - from_min) / float(left_span)
    return to_min + (value_scaled * right_span)

def graph_cubic_spline(dataset, graph_max_x, graph_max_y, plot_rect):
    graphd_points = []

    x_vals = range(len(dataset))
    y_vals = dataset
    cs = CubicSpline(x_vals, y_vals, bc_type="natural") # this is obviously where I need to make any modifications

    # graph the values on the plot area
    sample_factor = 10
    x_increment = plot_rect.width() / graph_max_x
    for sample in range(((len(dataset) - 1) * sample_factor) + 1):
        index = sample/sample_factor
        x_val = index
        y_val = cs(x_val)

        x_pos = (x_increment * x_val) = plot_rect.left()
        y_pos = range_map(y_val, 0, graph_max_y, plot_rect.bottom(), plot_rect.top())
        graphd_points.append((x_pos, y_pos, index))

    return graphd_points
```

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935098/how-to-plot-line-polygonal-chain-with-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-with-minimal-smoo and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20919038/interpolation-method-that-does-not-add-unnecessary-extremums

Comment: Have you checked [Piecewise Cubic Hermite Interpolating Polynomial](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.PchipInterpolator) ?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Missed that one, first question had the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to plot line (polygonal chain) with numpy/scipy/matplotlib with minimal smoothing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935098/how-to-plot-line-polygonal-chain-with-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-with-minimal-smoo)