# monotonic smoothing for noisy series

Tags: python, scipy, smoothing

I am hoping to get a smooth monotonic curve after it is run on my data.  To facilitate that, I have looked at a two step process - `savgol_filter` (from `scipy.signal`) run on the original (x,y) and then `PchipInterpolator` (from `scipy.interpolate`).

Couple of my datasets are here: [c2](https://pastebin.com/raw/c1zruNzz) | [c6](https://pastebin.com/raw/VZrWXekq)

The input columns are score (x), calib (y).  When `savgol = savgol_filter(calib,201,3)` is run, I get column `savgol`.  When I run `pchip = PchipInterpolator(score, savgol)` the series `pchip` is almost exactly the same as `savgol`; certainly not monotonic.

I am looking for help (python code not R) on how to run `Pchip...` correctly and/or how to get a smooth monotonic series given input `(score, calib)`.

Comment: The `PchipInterpolator` provides monotonic interpolation *between* data points.  If you only evaluate the interpolator at the input points, you will get the input values back.  That's what an interpolator does.

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935098/how-to-plot-line-polygonal-chain-with-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-with-minimal-smoo