# how to interpolate a cumulative function in python

Tags: python-3.x, scipy, interpolation, spline, cumulative-sum

I have a cumulative function (CDF) made of 6 points. I have to interpolate it so I used interp1d (from scipy.interpolate import interp1d), the results is the following:

[image]

the blue dots are the initial data and the red curve is after linear intepolation.
However, I am not really happy about it especially between the point 4 and 5 the assumption of linear relation is underestimating the real curve (if I think of this curve as a sigmoid or hyperbolic tangent). Therefore I tried to use always interp1d but with quadratic and cubic and the result is catastrofic[image]

the output makes no sense and it completely wrong, so my question is

how to make my original linear fit a bit more smooth and similar to a real cumulative function?
Thanks, Luigi

Comment: See, for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935098/how-to-plot-line-polygonal-chain-with-numpy-scipy-matplotlib-with-minimal-smoo/12936696#12936696

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, yes I did that approach and the result is not bad. However, since my curve is a CDF i would like to fit a lognormal CDF rather than a monotonic cubic..can you help with it? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try monotone interpolants, akima/pchip

Comment: yes as Warren suggested above I did it and that is not bad but I was more interested into fitting, in least square sense, a lognormal cumulative distribution as in reality my data point is a cumulative distribution (percentile in y axis, price in x axis).

Comment: Then your best bet is to try fitting the data and ask a separate question and if you have further problems